What chat app does not block our offline access to our messages in case we have any account problem? my messages are my property, not theirs!
What chat app does not block our offline access to our messages in case we have any account problem? my messages are my property, not theirs!!!
My messages are mine, not theirs! They have not the right to block me out of accessing my messages at least offline. They can block me accessing their servers, but my messages are not their property. This is total abuse of power.
On whatsapp, they told me some bug on their side locked me out of my account, and the above problem happened.
Now I am using telegramX, but can I trust it?
I need to know what chat apps wont lock me out of my messages if any problem happens to my account? It doenst matter if it is their fault or my fault, the point here is: my messages are my property, not theirs. If they cant respect that, I cant trust them anymore.

If you read the T&Cs for just about any such site you will find that by posting to them you are giving them possession of the messages. Usually with the right to delete or withhold them for a range or reasons - they also reserve the right to pass the message content on to various legal authorities in given circumstances.

I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be designed to provoke debate about services & providers rather than asking for software.

@SteveBarnes I get it. I thought someone could answer what you said  also, we got used to accept such abuses and we dont question anymore... feel free to close it, but as i still need a respectul app, i will try to recreate this question without the objectionable parts that seem to make ppl unconfortable. I will just wait this one get closed.

You should be able to edit your question without waiting for it to be closed (if it is). It is important to remember that a chat app actually just gives you access to a service which has T&Cs. The service providers are normally required by law, (where they are based), to block access under some conditions. You could try for an app that stores or can be set to store all messages locally on your machine.

Soon you'll have to worry about governments regularly scanning your messages, yet you worry about mesages not belonging to you. Anyways, the question is really poorly constructed, so here's a downvote. You should focus on how the software should function, not on ranting. E.g. do you expect a software where you own account/messages and that is a major communicator made by a known company, which people can easily download and use? If so, good luck. If you're instead looking for e.g. a communicator that you set up locally to use with friends, that should be specified

Or if you'd like something that auto backs up messages to cloud. Hard to answer without knowing what the goals of the app usage are

@Destroy666 I just want to have access to my messages (received or sent) offline, no matter what mistake or abuse they do against us. My question was properly understood too, there is Delta Chat app. The ranting part is our cry for justice and respect, it is the reason for this question to exist. They can do mistakes and abuse their power agsinst any of you, and now you know it because of my ranting. We did not stop being humans after all, right?

I don't think that's a chat, just something that pretends to be one, but to each their own. That's why you ask detailed questions so that everyone knows you don't need e.g. fully reliable instant messaging aspect

@SteveBarnes Btw, I was thinking, nowadays we do not really have any option, as a single agree is not optional, is mandatory. So Terms and conditions REAL options should not be just Agree or Cancel, it should be "Agree fully with all fanciness we can imagine", "Agree with the minimum required by law" (no fancy stuff is allowed here, but minimum service will be provided) or Cancel. I am looking for a place to properly suggest this as a topic, so all this abuse could end, any idea?

You can use Delta Chat, based on email, for which you can use any email server. By virtue of being based on email, you hold the messages that you send and receive, and can easily synchronize them to an offline email client using POP for instance. Losing access to your email account does not make you lose past messages.
There is an Android client.
Unlike other solutions like IRC, it allows you to communicate with most people, as most people already have an email account.
Free and open source.

Descentralized is the word that brings hope nowadays, thx! Gonna test it as soon i can :)
